How to create Persistent Volume Claim in Kubernetes with Ansible?
I am trying to install Unifi on a Kubernetes cluster server (K3S) using Ansible and ran into troubles when trying to define a persistent volume claim.
I am using Kubernetes.Core module and I have defined my task as:
- name: Define storage space for Unifi
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      metadata:
        name: unifi-cluster-pvc
        namespace: default
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: longhorn
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi

However when I run my playbook then I get the following error:
TASK [unifi : Define storage space for Unifi] 
***********************************************************************
fatal: [central.example.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": 
"Failed to create object: b'{\"kind\":\"Status\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",
\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"message\":\"PersistentVolumeClaim 
\\\\\"unifi-cluster-pvc\\\\\" is invalid: spec.resources[storage]: Required 
value\",\"reason\":\"Invalid\",\"details\":{\"name\":\"unifi-cluster-pvc\",
\"kind\":\"PersistentVolumeClaim\",\"causes\":[{\"reason\":\"FieldValueRequired\",
\"message\":\"Required value\",\"field\":\"spec.resources[storage]\"}]},\"code\":422}\\n'", 
"reason": "Unprocessable Entity"}

Is there anyone who can explain what is going on?
Because if I create a yaml file called test.yml with the following content:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: unifi-cluster-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: longhorn
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi

and run the command: kubectl apply -f test.yml on my controller
Then I get the message back:
persistentvolumeclaim/unifi-cluster-pvc created


The error is indicating that the resource block is required to create the PVC.
Seems like you missed the indentation of the pvc definition file at resources block because the resources is a sub block of spec. You can update the task as mentioned below
- name: Define storage space for Unifi
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      metadata:
        name: unifi-cluster-pvc
        namespace: default
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: longhorn
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 100Mi

For more detailed information about pvc definition check this official Kubernetes document on Persistent Volume Claim.

I knew it was something like that. Because anything after the line containing definition: is a straight up copy-paste from kubernetes yaml file. I really should make a script that generates an ansible task given a kubernetes yaml file. :-)
